# How to chain text with moviepy

Tags: video, video-processing, moviepy

I need to highlight a part of a string with a different color using moviepy.
For example: my string is "hello every body, I am very happy to be here".
I want the string is black but the word "happy" is green!

I tried but it doesn't work:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
t1 = TextClip("hello every body, I am very ", color="black")
t2 = TextClip("happy", color="green")
t3 = TextClip(" to be here", color="black")
clips = concatenate([t1, t2, t3], method="chain")
clips.write_videofile('text.mp4', fps=24)
```

Please help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use method='pango' and watch here for pango markup languange options [MoviePy Website](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/)